# formControl and ngModel

Tags: angular, binding, ngmodel

I have the following code on angular

```
<div *ngFor="let student of students.controls; let i=index" [formGroupName]="i" [class.active]="student.checked">
    <!-- The repeated address template -->
    <h4>Student #{{i + 1}}
        <input type="checkbox" formControlName="checked" [(ngModel)]="student.checked">
    </h4>
    <div class="form-group">
        <label class="center-block">First Name:
            <input class="form-control" formControlName="firstName">
        </label>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <label class="center-block">Last name:
        <input class="form-control" formControlName="lastName">
        </label>
    /div>
</div>
```

here is my css

```
div.active{
  background-color:#CCFFCC !important;
}
```

at this line

The problem is when the checkBox is checked the background color of my array element containing the checkbox become green as I want but the formControlName "checked" is not taken into account and when I delete `[(ngModel)]="student.checked"` I don't have the background color changing behaviour anymore but the formControlName "checked" works

Actual behaviour, I build my array with an imported student having the properties checked true, the box is not checked but when I check it the background become green

Wanted behaviour : I build my array with an imported student having the properties checked true, the box is checked and when I uncheck it the green background disappear (my ngModel `[(ngModel)]="student.checked"` is bind with the formControlName "checked")

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've found the solution

```
<div *ngFor="let student of students.controls; let i=index" 
[formGroupName]="i" [class.active]="student.controls.checked.value>
    <!-- The repeated address template -->
    <h4>Student #{{i + 1}}
        <input type="checkbox" formControlName="checked">
    </h4>
```

This code works

Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 0):

try this, use ngClass

```
<div [ngClass]="{'active':student.checked}">...</div>
```

in div tag put student, you have strudent, change it

Comment: Unfortunately, it doesn't work,It does the same behaviour than with  [class.active]="student.checked" by the way I made a typo simplifying the example in my code I do have [class.active]="student.checked" and I also Tried <div [ngClass]="{'active':student.checked}">...</div>

Comment: you have import CommonModule

Comment: you have strudent in div and in checkbox student, that is the problem